# Checkbox to send only specific rows to php form parser

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to use a form with php.

I populate the form info from a database.

The form input is separated into rows.

The form offers a checkbox to only pass that row of data and what is supposed to happen is when I parse the data in the form parsing document I only get the rows that were checked.

However what's happening is that the $_POST method for the checkbox array will only return what's checked, but all the other input arrays still contain all the rows, even the ones that aren't checked.

```
<?php



while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $id = $row["id"];
        $email = $row["user_email"];
    $androidId = $row["user_androidid"];
    $amount = $row["amount"];

    echo "<tr>
    <td><input id='data_id' name='data_id[]' size='25'  value='".$id."'/></td>
    <td><input id='mail' name='mail[]'size='25' value='".$email."'/></td>
    <td><input id='androidId' name='androidId[]' size='25' value='".$androidId."'/></td>
    <td><input id='amount' name='amount[]' size='25' value='".$amount."'/></td>
    <td>coming soon...</td>
    <td><input id='currency' name='currencyCode[]' size='25' value='USD'/></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='chosen[]' value='".$id."'<td>
    </tr>";



}
?>
```

And I'm testing it like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST["chosen"]); $i++){

echo $_POST["chosen"][$i];

}
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST["mail"]); $i++){

echo $_POST["mail"][$i];

}
```

For a specific example right now I have three rows, I "check" the first and the last.

When I parse the form data the checkbox array returns the values for the first and the last only, but if I try to parse the mail[] it has all the values for rows 1, 2, and 3.

Any ideas on how to properly configure this? I'm sure there's something wrong with the structure, just looking for confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try linking the input arrays together by giving them the same key, in this case `$id` -

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $id = $row["id"];
        $email = $row["user_email"];
    $androidId = $row["user_androidid"];
    $amount = $row["amount"];

    echo "<tr>
    <td><input id='data_id' name='data_id[".$id."]' size='25'  value='".$id."'/></td>
    <td><input id='mail' name='mail[".$id."]'size='25' value='".$email."'/></td>
    <td><input id='androidId' name='androidId[".$id."]' size='25' value='".$androidId."'/></td>
    <td><input id='amount' name='amount[".$id."]' size='25' value='".$amount."'/></td>
    <td>coming soon...</td>
    <td><input id='currency' name='currencyCode[".$id."]' size='25' value='USD'/></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='chosen[".$id."]' value='".$id."'/><td>
    </tr>"; 
}
```

Then on the post you can get only the arrays that were checked -

```
foreach($_POST["chosen"] as $key=>$value){
     echo $_POST["data_id"][$key];
     echo $_POST["mail"][$key];
     echo $_POST["androidId"][$key];
     echo $_POST["amount"][$key];
     echo $_POST["currencyCode"][$key];
     echo $_POST["chosen"][$key];
}
```

Comment: Sean, can you help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930440/wrap-some-inputs-with-its-check-box-and-send-to-database

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a better structure, that way you will have an array of values with the id as key, and an array of chosen values that holds the selected keys. Check also html errors that you have as `<td><input type='checkbox' name='chosen[]' value='".$id."'<td>`

```
echo "<tr>
<td><input id='data_id' name='".$id."[data_id]' size='25'  value='".$id."'/></td>
<td><input id='mail' name='".$id."[mail]' size='25' value='".$email."'/></td>
<td><input id='androidId' name='".$id."[androidId]' size='25' value='".$androidId."'/></td>
<td><input id='amount' name='".$id."[amount]' size='25' value='".$amount."'/></td>
<td>coming soon...</td>
<td><input id='currency' name='".$id."[currency]' size='25' value='USD'/></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='chosen[]' value='".$id."'/></td>
</tr>";
```

Now the PHP for testing:

```
if ( !empty($_POST['chosen']) ) {
    foreach ( $_POST['chosen'] as $value ) {
        print_r( $_POST[$value] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do a **var_dump($_POST)** and look at what you're getting sent overall because it amazes me (unless I have misunderstood) that you are getting the information (and only that information) for the row with the checkbox checked. For starters, if you don´t specify a "type" in your input type, the default type will be of "text". Which means you can edit whatever is in that textbox, so that when you hit the submit button (whether you have checked one of the check boxes **or not**) all of the values inside each text box are going to be sent.

There are multiple ways of doing what you need (processing only the information that belongs to the row with the checked checkbox).

Javascript help:

1. Add a function called disable(), that will be called whenever your submit button is pressed. This function is in charge of going through the values of the unchecked check boxes rows and setting the text box's to "disabled", that way they won´t get sent to the server.

The pros of this is that ONLY the information associated to the checked check box is going to be sent, and you won´t have to worry about filtering through in the server.

Cosn,if you are not used to javascript this obviously is no help.

PHP server side:

I just saw Sean's answer, and it´s a good one, you could do that if you wanted to validate on the server instead. Just let me warn you though that the user could edit your text box data, for example, leave it empty or add what he pleases, and when he sends it and you try to access it via  $_POST[input_name][$key] you won´t get what you had established from the server.

Comment: +1 I like your suggestion about using javascript to disable before submitting. I debated about including that in my answer, but opted not to, so I am glad that you posted that suggestion.

Comment: Javascript is a real help at times. And your answer is great, I hadn´t realized you could do it like that, you save plenty of filtering, koodus!