# Wrap some inputs with its check-box and send to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

The point is "how can I select all the input elements in the same row as the checked check-box?"

```
MARK       NAME                   QUANTITY                      PRICE      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 []     inputForName1         inputForQuantity1             inputForPrice1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 []     inputForName2         inputForQuantity2             inputForPrice2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 []     inputForName3         inputForQuantity3             inputForPrice3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 []     inputForName4         inputForQuantity4             inputForPrice4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 []     inputForName5         inputForQuantity5             inputForPrice5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                              [SUBMIT]
```

(here "[]" is a Check-Box)

When some of the lists in checked, then all on its row (the inputs) is selected.

And then, how to submit the checked box, for example if there are two of checkboxes which are checked, then all input in the two checkboxes are send to a table in database.

Please give me an idea how to do this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where did you get stuck with your own attempts? Are you able, or willing, to use a JavaScript library? (It's ***not*** required to use a library, I just thought I'd forestall the "it's easy, here's teh jQuery!" answers if it's not used in your project.) Incidentally: `<input>` elements are *void* elements, they cannot 'contain' either any other elements, or any text at all. Second, what's your HTML, what do you mean by 'selected' and, finally, this is a very broad question (which is a bad sign): what *part* of this multi-faceted question do you want help with?

Comment: Or course I am looking for the smart way on how to do this. As I am not sure how  to do this, that's way I tag all the programming language which may be the way how to do this.

Comment: The point is only to submit all which are checked.

Comment: Narrow your question down into smaller steps. First, I'd suggest restricting this question to: "how can I select all the input elements in the same row as the checked check-box?" (for example, but this *still* depends on what you mean by 'select the input elements.') Once that problem is solved, then move onto the next step (with a new question, if there isn't already a question about that step). Also: show us your attempts, demonstrate your research, show us your HTML. As it is this seems like you're asking us how to build an aspect of your website for you (which I hope isn't true).

Comment: you can just treat this as just a normal form submission, just get that ids.

Comment: @Ghost Did you mean that I can make multiple forms for this?

Comment: @klaudia what do you mean multiple forms? maybe you mean multiple checked items. yes just name it as a grouping name. `input type="checkbox" name="inputs[echo id here]"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329376/how-to-post-checked-rows-data-from-a-table

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942994/checkbox-to-send-only-specific-rows-to-php-form-parser

Answer (score 2):

It is not so hard, for this HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Mark</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[1]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name[1]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity[1]" size="3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price[1]" size="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[2]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name[2]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity[2]" size="3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price[2]" size="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[3]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name[3]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity[3]" size="3" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price[3]" size="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input id="save" type="button" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h3>Post data:</h3>
<div class="submit_data">click Submit...</div>
```

Complete jQuery snippet would be:

```
$('input[name^=id]').on('change', function(e) {
    var thisCheckbox = $(this);
    var thisRow = thisCheckbox.closest('tr');
    if ( thisCheckbox.is(':checked') ) {
        thisRow.addClass('row_selected');
    } else {
        thisRow.removeClass('row_selected');
    };
});
$('#save').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toPost = $('.row_selected input').serialize();
    /* Now post and insert into database */
    $.post('insert_into_db.php', toPost, function(data) {
        alert('Success!');
    });
});
```

[See the code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/smtcp7r6/1/).

In PHP posted variables are arrays as:

```
[id] => Array
    (
        [1] => on
        [3] => on
    )

[name] => Array
    (
        [1] => My name 1
        [3] => My name 3
    )

[quantity] => Array
    (
        [1] => 100
        [3] => 50
    )

[price] => Array
    (
        [1] => 23.34
        [3] => 15.23
    )
```

and you can browse them this way:

```
foreach( $_POST['id'] as $id=>$on ) {
    echo 'ID: ' . $id . '<br />';
    echo 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'][$id] . '<br />';
    echo 'Qty: ' . $_POST['quantity'][$id] . '<br />';
    echo 'Price: ' . $_POST['price'][$id] . '<br />';
    echo '<hr />';
};
```

which outputs:

```
ID: 1
Name: My name 1
Qty: 100
Price: 23.34
------------------
ID: 3
Name: My name 3
Qty: 50
Price: 15.23
------------------
```

Please note: on some of devices you will need to turn off jQuery caching, in general:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

or post specific:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   type: 'POST',
   headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, skobaljic. Now if I want to post it, Will all the check box is posted if I do this like this?: `$name=$_POST['name']; $quantity=$_POST['quantity']; $price=$_POST['price'];`

Comment: No, `$_POST['name']` will be an array, so you go `foreach($_POST['name'] as $id=>$name){};`.

Comment: Can you please give me the full example for this, and with var_dump($_POST) to ensure if all the selected rows are posted? I am still a little bit confused on how to do this, especially when it has to combine javascript with php. I do really need a help, here,because I works alone.