# Insert only Checkbox Selected Row Values into a MySQL Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below JSFiddle link is that of a working form, where submitted form values from dynamic rows gets saved to a mysql table using ajax without any page refresh. The outcome of the form submission (i.e Success or Error) will be shown in a div which has an id 'results' using javascript.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/um4fc0wv/12/)

Form Markup

```
    <form name="names" id="names" method="post" action="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success addmore">Add</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">Remove</button>
      <br />
      <table id="demo" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <input class="check_all" type="checkbox" onclick="select_all()" />
            </th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" class="case" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname[]" id="fname_1" required>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname[]" id="lname_1" required>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="results"></div>
<div id="results2"></div>
</div>
<!-- ./table-responsive -->

</div>
```

Javascript for Add/Remove Table Rows, Checkbox Row(s) Selection

```
    $(".delete").on('click', function() {
  $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
  $('.check_all').prop("checked", false);
  check();
});


var i = $('table tr').length;


$(".addmore").on('click', function() {
  count = $('table tr').length;
  var data = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>";
  data += "<td><input class='form-control' id='fname_" + i + "' name='fname[]' required/></td>";
  data += "<td><input class='form-control' id='lname_" + i + "' name='lname[]' required/></td></tr>";
  //alert(data);
  $('table').append(data);
  row = i;
  i++;
});



function select_all() {
  $('input[class=case]:checkbox').each(function() {
    if ($('input[class=check_all]:checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
    } else {
      $(this).prop("checked", true);

    }
  });
}

function check() {
  obj = $('table tr').find('span');
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    id = value.id;
    var selected = $('#' + id).html(key + 1);

  });
}
```

Javascript for Form Submission using Ajax

```
    // form submission through ajax
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#names").on("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "savename.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
          if (response == "Name creation successfull.") {
            $("#results").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close">×</button>' + response + '</div><br>');

          } else {
            $("#results2").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close">×</button>' + response + '</div><br>');

          }

          //timing the alert box to close after 5 seconds
          window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {
              $(this).remove();
            });
          }, 2000);

          //Adding a click event to the 'x' button to close immediately
          $('.alert .close').on("click", function(e) {
            $(this).parent().fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500);
          });
          $('#names')[0].reset();


        },
        error: function(response) {
          alert(response);
        }
      });
    });
  });

});
```

What I like to implement is this,

1. User first selects the rows which he/she wants to insert into the mysql table by selecting the checkbox at the beginning of each row.
2. After selecting the rows, upon clicking the submit button only those selected row values should be inserted into the mysql table.

   Tried to implement this by trying out the solutions from various posts similar to this one on this site but was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Used the solution provided by the user skobaljic (Thank you very much) in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930440/wrap-some-inputs-with-its-check-box-and-send-to-database) post. Using this code now am able to post only those form values which are from the selected rows to a mysql table.

[Updated JSFiddle Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/um4fc0wv/18/)

Following line is for debugging purpose only, comment out after you are done.

```
$('.submit_data').text(toPost);
```

While the code works and gets the job done, am just a novice when it comes to javascript, so need expert opinion to mark this post as solved.